# Replace hyphen with space using bash

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm reading a filename that has this data:

```
2017-03-23
2018-01-23
2017-07-31
```

I want to read each line and replace the hyphens with spaces. Given the above example, I should get the following:

```
2017 03 23
2018 01 23
2017 07 31
```

Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/sh

filename=extract_dates.dat
line=1
totline=`wc -l < $filename`

while [ $line -le $totline ]
do
    date=`sed -n -e ''"$line"'p' $filename | awk '{print $line}'`
    echo $date
    test=`sed 's/([0-9])-([0-9])/\1\2/g' $date`
    echo $test
    line=`expr $line + 1`
done
```

I get the following error:

```
sed: 1: "s/([0-9])-([0-9])/\1\2/g": \1 not defined in the RE
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

tr will replace hyphens with spaces, for example:

```
test=$(echo $date | tr "-" " ")
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need explicit counters or `sed` or `awk`; `bash` itself can handle this. (Your use of `awk`, especially, doesn't really do anything.)

```
filename=extract_dates.dat

while IFS=- read -r year month day; do
    echo "Year: $year"
    echo "Month: $month"
    echo "Day: $day"
done < "$filename"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use string replacement of bash instead

```bash
#!/bin/bash

input="2017-03-23
2018-01-23
2017-07-31"

output="${input//-/ }"
echo "$output"
```

Outputs

```
2017 03 23
2018 01 23
2017 07 31
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
tr '-' ' ' < filename > output
```

If you want to use `sed`, you could use that as well. The reason your `sed` command doesn't work is that you need to escape your paranthesis. Try this:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\)-\([0-9]\)/\1\2/g' $date
```

Comment: I have a long script. I need to assign it to a new variable in order to use the variable later.

Comment: What do you want to store in the variable?

Comment: the new date, as in `echo $test` should print out `2017 03 23`

Comment: You could pipe the output to `read` and read it one by one. Anyway, the reason your `sed` doesn't work is that you need to escape the parantheses. I'll update my answer with that solution as well.